# Многофункциональный плеер для Linux

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте. Посоветуйте какой нибудь многофункциональный расширяемый видео-плеер для линукс(я использую suse). Обязательно наличие таких опций как выключение компьютера по окончании плейлиста, подключение внешних звуковых дорожек.Искал в и-нете, ничего толкового не нашел.Иными словами хотелось бы что-то вроде KMPlayer'a под windows. Заранее благодарю за совет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то мне думается, что выключение компа и проигрывание музыки совсем разные вещи. Почитайте, что такое [Unix Way](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_way).

А вообще вот - [vlc shutdown after playback linux](http://bit.ly/J7jYfX).

Comment: Проигрывание видео

Comment: Я к тому, что Linux не Windows, тут комбайнов не жалуют..вашу проблему можно решить к примеру так, ставьте проиграыватель VLCи запускайте (скриптом, или руками как пожелаете)        vlc --play-and-exit ./path/to/video/file.mpg && shutdown -h now (или poweroff)

Answer (score 1):

KMPlayer есть и под Linux. VLC мне не очень нравится именно из за его навороченности. Музыку предпочитаю слушать в Audacious, не навороченный, и при том достаточно полнофункциональный. Многолетний опыт работы в Linux разных дистрибутивов убеждает в лучшей работе именно простейших программ. Всё сильно зависит и от оборудования и запросов пользователя. Все программы есть в репозиторях, именно оттуда и надо ставить.